# Is there any text editor with autocomplete?

Tags: text-editor, autocomplete

I'm programmer myself, so I'm used to using autocomplete in various forms in various IDEs. Right now I'm writing my master thesis and it struck me, that I don't know any editor with word autocompletition. I'm not talking about keyword completition, but natural language one.

Yes, MS Office and Libre/Open Office can complete some words, but the support is rather poor at best. On mobile platform there are many smart keyboards which offer autocorrect and autocompletition. One example would SwiftKey for Android, which learns your typing style and offers you next word in sentence automatically.

Is there something like that for personal computers? Windows preferably, but Unix is fine too.

UPDATE: I'm looking for some solution which would speed-up writing in text editors in similar way programming IDEs work. This means the editor would provide me with list of option which would fit the sentence based on what I have written so far. Or the editor would provide me with list of words based on few letters.

Comment: Emacs, probably, but before I write an answer, could you clarify what you're after? Word completion or correction? Based on a static dictionary or learning from what you type? Predictable or context-sensitive?

Comment: I think Sublime text has some natural language and programming language auto-complete from when I last used it that didn't appear to be context sensitive to the language I was using. It seemed to include predictions from English and previously used syntax (learning). However, I would certainly not want to write a _document_ in Sublime text unless it was in Markdown as it has no formatting.

Lastly, I'm not sure why auto-completing would help in natural language at all, I would think it would slow down typing as you're constantly hitting enter/space/tab to complete, or constantly fighting it.

Comment: @JordanMcGuigan I'm really used to SwiftKey where it really speed up things. The main benefit for me is, that it can "make sense of the mess I touch". Basically you touch the general location of the letters and the words appear.

Comment: hitting tab (f.e.) is way quicker than typing 'lirious' if it is smart enough to suggest 'delirious' after you type 'de' because you've been writing delirious a lot lately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you use a voice recognition software such as Dragon NaturallySpeaking if you care about your writing speed. However, if you want to stick to the keyboard you can use Emacs + [PredictiveMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PredictiveMode):

- is free
- supports Unix and [Windows](https://superuser.com/q/326431/116475)
- provides a list of words based on few letters.

For more features: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PredictiveMode#toc7

Answer (score 5):

You may try [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) with [Dictionary Auto-Complete](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/DictionaryAutoComplete) package. **This package will provide you a list of words based on few letters**. 
Sublime Text also supports spell check. To enable spell check:

1. Go to Preferences → Settings ‐ User.
2. Add this line in the opened file: `"spell_check": true` and save that file.

Answer (score 1):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) does what you want.

It can autocomplete previously entered natural language words (no dictionary, just what you typed before), programming language functions, or both.

Go to "Settings" → "Preferences" → "Auto-Completion".

You can choose whether to complete words, functions, or both, and after how many typed letters the auto-completion has to kick in.