# Autocomplete text in any Windows application?

Tags: windows, open-source, text-editor, autocomplete

I know that [many text editors have autocomplete features or third-party plugins](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3151/is-there-any-text-editor-with-autocomplete), but is there a Windows autocomplete software that works **in any application**? (Could be Chrome, Firefox, MS Word, notepad, Notepad++, or any other program with a textbox.)

I'm looking for an open-source equivalent (or even more basic) to https://www.lightkey.io/predictive-text-in-any-application.

[image]